# wso2 application creation using using rest api,

Tags: wso2, store

While creating application in wso2 i need to send Bearer token. But for login wso2 /token api i need an application

apim:subscribei
Request 
POST https://localhost:9443/api/am/store/v0.12/applications
Authorization: Bearer ae4eae22-3f65-387b-a171-d37eaa366fa8

{
    "throttlingTier": "Unlimited",
    "description": "sample app description",
    "name": "sampleapp",
    "callbackUrl": "http://my.server.com/callback"
}
Ref:https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/apidocs/store/index.html#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsApplicationIdKeysKeyTypeGet

Answer (score 2):

Please read the `Getting started` link on the same page.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/apidocs/store/index.html#guide

Eg.

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.12/register
```

Sample request body:

```
{
    "callbackUrl": "www.google.lk",
    "clientName": "rest_api_store",
    "owner": "admin",
    "grantType": "password refresh_token",
    "saasApp": true
}
```